# How to access json array through key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, x-editable

When i print this: `console.log( response );`

It gives me this json array:

```
{    
    "myStudentId":17,
    "myName":"beng",
    "myAge":38,
    "myAddress":"Los Angeles, California, USA.",
    "myGender":"Female",
    "myReligion":"Catholic",
    "myStatus":"boom",
    "myOccupation":"Actress",
    "myEducationLevel":"Undefined",
    "graduate":true
}
```

I want to access the `graduate` value. What I tried so far is:

```
console.log( response["graduate"] );
console.log( response.graduate );
```

But this all returns `undefined`. Is there a way to do this? If possible I don't want to use loop. I want to access it through key if only possible.

**EDIT:**

I'm using [x-editable success method](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable) for the call back.

```
$(this).editable({
    pk: pk,
    name: id,
    url: '../admin/edit_studentInfo.do',
    validate: function( value ) {
       if($.trim( value ) == '') {
          return 'This field is required';
       } else if( isNaN( value ) && id == 'age' ) {
          return 'Only accepts numbers';
       }
        },
    success: function(response, newValue) { // call back
       var test = response;
       console.log( JSON.stringify(response) );
       console.log( response );
       console.log( response["graduate"] );
       console.log( response["myName"] + ', ' + response.myName );
    }
});
```

I included my editable initialization and also the test

Comment: This is an object.Not an array

Comment: cab you say `console.log(JSON.stringify(response ))`

Comment: I have a feeling you either 1. still have a string as the response (jQuery "intelligent guess" sometimes fails) 2. doing an async call wrong. It would be better to have the remaining code posted here.

Comment: If you parsing it through ajax.make sure to use dataType:"JSON"

Comment: @samitha i'll look into it. I'm using [x-editable success method](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable) for the response.

Comment: That's not a JSON array. (It's a JSON object o_0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response` is a string. You need to parse it as JSON before you can access any of the properties of the encoded object:

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(response.graduate);
```

Alternately, tell use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or pass `dataType : "JSON"` and jQuery will do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ajaxOption

```
ajaxOptions: {
dataType: 'json'
}
```